# Dynamically generated fields not saving

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a database with multiple tables. one is used as static source of information to be entered in a other table. I created a form where this first table is being looped and used to build input fields. These field have a checkbox, and ideally, if that checkbox is checked it would save that field to the second table once submitted.

However, it doesn't save to the second table at all, while the rest of that
form(nested form) does.

How does this come? I do not get any errors in the server log.

Part of the _form. Contains a total of 6 blocks like this and 2 other blocks. The other blocks do save properly:

```
 <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
              <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                Product (vrij) verklaring
              </a>
            </h5>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
            <div class="card-block">

              <%= f.fields_for :enquirymeasures do |em| %>

                  <%= Measurement.where(measurementtype: 'product verklaring').find_each do |m| %>

                      <%= f.fields_for :enquirymeasures, :html => {:multipart => true} do |em| %>
                          <%# em.hidden_field :measurementid, {:value => m.id} %>
                          <%= em.text_field :type, {:value => m.measurementtype} %>
                          <%= em.text_field :description, {:value => m.measurement} %>
                          <p>
                            <%= em.check_box :needed %>
                            <%= m.measurement %>


                          <hr>
                      <% end %>
                  <% end %>
                  <%= f.fields_for :enquirymeasures do |em| %>
                      <%= em.label :bijzonderheden %>
                      <%= em.text_field :other %></p>
                  <% end %>

                  <br>


                  </div>
                  </div>

              <% end %>
              </div>


        <%= f.fields_for :enquirymeasures do |em| %>
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingElektro">
                <h5 class="mb-0">
                  <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseElektro" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseElektro">
                    Elektrotechnische maatregelen
                  </a>
                </h5>
              </div>
              <div id="collapseElektro" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingElektro">
                <div class="card-block">
                  <%= Measurement.where(measurementtype: 'Elektrotechnisch').find_each do |m| %>

                      <%= f.fields_for :enquirymeasures, :html => {:multipart => true} do |em| %>
                          <%= em.hidden_field :measurementid, {:value => m.id} %>
                          <%= em.hidden_field :type, {:value => m.measurementtype} %>
                          <%= em.hidden_field :description, {:value => m.measurement} %>
                          <p><%= em.check_box :needed %> <%= m.measurement %>
                          <hr>
                      <% end %>
                  <% end %>
                  <%= f.fields_for :enquirymeasures do |em| %>
                      <%= em.label :bijzonderheden %>
                      <%= em.text_field :other %></p>
                  <% end %>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

        <% end %>
        </div>
```

Permitted attributes:

```
 def enquiry_params
      params.require(:enquiry).permit(:reference, :location, :description, :date, :amount, :approved, :status,
                                      enquirymeasures_attributes: [:id, :done, :needed, :measurement_id, :measurementid, :user, :other, :type, :description],
                                      tools_attributes: [:id, :handtool, :other, :motorvehicle, :compressor, :ramp, :scaffold, :crane, :ladder, :generator, :tankladder],
                                      applicant_attributes: [:id, :name, :email, :contractor_id, :company],
                                      signatures_attributes: [:id, :date, :representative_id],
                                      gasmeters_attributes: [:id, :date, :tester, :signature, :oxigen, :o_needed, :o_continu, :explosives, :e_needed, :e_continu, :mat1, :mat1_needed, :mat1_continu, :mat2, :mat2_needed, :mat2_continu, :mat3, :mat3_needed, :mat3_continu],
                                      controls_attributes: [:id, :enquirycheck, :workspacecheck, :enquiry_id],
                                      roles_attributes: [:name],
                                      user_attributes: [:id, :name, :company]).merge(user_id: current_user.id)
    end
```

The create function

```
def create
    @enquiry.user_id = current_user.id
    @enquiry = Enquiry.new(enquiry_params)
    #@enquiry.enquirymeasures.build


    respond_to do |format|
      if @enquiry.save
        format.html { redirect_to @enquiry, notice: 'Enquiry was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @enquiry }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @enquiry.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

THe database models:

```
table #1class Measurement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :enquirymeasure

  belongs_to :enquiry

  def type_and_measurement
    "#{self.measurementtype} |"  " #{self.measurement}"
  end
end


table #2
class Enquirymeasure < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :enquiry
  has_many :measurements
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :measurements
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And i found the solution. 
I was using :type as a columnname in the enquirymeasures table. This, offcourse, doesn't work due to it being a reserver word and all. (something i knew all along but just didn't think about or something)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your models relationships correctly it seems to me that Enquiry is the model that should have the nested attributes for measurement, you should

```
 pass accepts_nested_attributes_for :measurements
```

From EnquiryMeasure to Enquiry